# Why does a solenoid's field look like this?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

[image]

My book gives the above diagram but doesn't provide an explanation why the field looks like that. It simply says that the fields mostly cancel leaving the field above.

Could someone walk me through how the field above is generated assuming that the magnetic field generated by a straight wire are a series of concentric circles?

Comment: have a look at this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid

Comment: I'm wondering if the principle of superposition is perfectly applicable here, or only imperfectly applicable.  Maybe it's irrelevant, since the only explicit expressions we have for the field from a wire apply for infinite wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew the magnetic field vector for each wire in red, and the resulting one with pink color. black lines are for a reference so you can see how magnetic vectors are at 90 degrees to the wires. if you draw something like this for every point inside the solenoid you'll see how the magnetic field is formed.

[image]

here's how it looks in real world:
[image]

Comment: Could you do the same thing to show me how the field outside a solenoid is zero?

Comment: @dfg, it's not zero, but it's very low. because the opposite wires will have magnetic vectors pointing in approximately opposite directions, with approximately equal magnitude, so they cancel each other out. you should do this yourself to understand how this works. pick any point outside, then draw a magnetic force from each wire on the picture, making sure that it's in right direction. just like i did.

Comment: Got it. Couple more questions. 1) Does this approximation of the field being almost zero become worse as the diameter of the solenoid increases? (since the opposite sides are further apart) And consequently do all the derived equations not apply for large solenoids? 2) Are solenoids approximated as a series of perfect circles (since opposite sides cancel only in a circle)? And consequently shouldn't a stretched out solenoid's field be completely different since its nothing like a series of circles?

Comment: A little help please?

Comment: @dfg You'd better ask new questions as new questions instead of doing it in comments. If your original question has been answered, please accept the answer by clicking a tick mark next to it..

Answer (score 1):

It results from the fact that every conductor in which flows a current generates a magnetic field which is concentric to it (iso-potential lines are concentric circles). The [Biot&Savart law](http://www.iit.edu/arc/workshops/pdfs/Georgi_Subashki_Workshop_Biot_Savart_Law.pdf) quantifies this behaviour under an integral form, and you can solve those equations in any point of space to get the distribution of the magnetic field (find it on the axis of a solenoid is actually a typical exercise for electromagnetism 101 in unis).

If you want an intuitive version, lines of field "embrace" themselves when they have the same direction and repel eachother when they don't, pretty much like electrostatic field does with charges (same idea).